# GSWD Heroku Django manage.py issue

Tags: django, heroku, django-manage.py

I worked my way through a great django tutorial online, but am having an issue with the final heroku deployment.

Here is the django tutorial:
http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/

The issue I have is with the last call to heroku:

`heroku python manage.py syncdb`

Here is the error I get:

```
(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.2530
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 177, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 178, in connect
    return _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$
```

Any thoughts

Comment: Did you add `import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {'default' : dj_database_url.config() }` to your `settings.py`? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings

Comment: And if not, you'd also need to add `dj-database-url==0.2.0` to your `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know ( git intermediate level knowledge ) If you forgot to add locals.py to the .gitignore file and committed it then the git repository will have the locals.py file still in it .

You have to remove the file from git repository since it was included in previous commits.

```
git rm --cached microblog/settings/local.py
```

Then add microblog/settings/local.py to .gitignore and commit the changes.

Once heroku sees the correct DATABASES setting . Then syncdb works fine

```
DATABASES = {'default' : dj_database_url.config() }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Wasn't working for me either becuse I didn't have local.py in my .gitignore file.

Answer (score 2):

did you add:
*microblog/settings/local.py* 
to the .gitignore file ?

if that doesn't work try commenting out the DATABASES = {....} bit in the local.py file and see if that works

https://github.com/kennethlove/gswd-transcripts/blob/master/lesson-01.md