# heroku postgresql won't syncdb

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, heroku

So...I a newbie working on a django app but when I try run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` through a virtualbox heroku but it keeps telling me this below:

```
  (blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.9695
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 177, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 178, in connect
    return _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This is the link that that wont load my admin page in my app when deployed to heroku.

http://sheltered-dusk-5757.herokuapp.com/admin/

And this is also following the heroku django guide as well. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings

The following is my tree:

```
(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ tree .
.
|-- manage.py
|-- microblog
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- settings
|   |   |-- base.py
|   |   |-- base.pyc
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |   |-- local.py
|   |   `-- local.pyc
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   |-- templates
|   |   |-- 500.html
|   |   `-- index.html
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- wsgi.py
|   `-- wsgi.pyc
|-- Procfile
`-- requirements.txt

3 directories, 18 files
```

Inside my settings folder: **init**.py

```
# settings/__init__.py
from .base import *

try: 
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

local.py

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'microblog',                      
        'USER': 'vagrant',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '5432',                      
    }
}
```

Base.py

```
import os
import dj_database_url
# here() gives us file paths from the root of the system to the directory
# holding the current file.
here = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)

PROJECT_ROOT = here("..")
# root() gives us file paths from the root of the system to whatever
# folder(s) we pass it starting at the parent directory of the current file.
root = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *x)

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
#    ('myname', 'email'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = root("..","static")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    root("assets"),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'i-5%d5z&amp;a8z95@&amp;8@x0k*4zczs#38s-ui0=99i6ck7bdy_3af4'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'microblog.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'microblog.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    root("templates"),
)



DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (

)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (

)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS


# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help guys.

**EDITED:: PROBLEM SOLVED**

Keep the base.py as:

```
DATABASES = {'default' : dj_database_url.config() }
```

Then Comment out the local.py database before deployment...

If a fatal error occurs: 
  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#fatal-role-rolename

Afterwards go into postgres.heroku.com and find the color of your database and promote it back into your app.

Everything should be working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

instead of what you have into settings right now

Answer (score 3):

I think what is happening here is your local.py file is checked into git and is being mistakenly used on Heroku. Try adding it to .gitignore or follow the advice in this answer. [GSWD Heroku Django manage.py issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574827/gswd-heroku-django-manage-py-issue)